# CKAN Datapusher configuration on Tomcat 7 (Windows 7)

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, ckan

I have done a source installation of CKAN 2.2.1 on my Windows 7 64 bit machine and installed 'Datastore', which is a prerequisite of Datapusher.

I followed the instructions of the official guide to install and configure the Datapusher.

http://docs.ckan.org/projects/datapusher/en/latest/#download-and-install-all-ckan-versions

However I have trouble configuring my Tomcat 7 with the Datapusher because the guide uses Apache Server. Their file directories are different.

E.G. There are no 'sites-available' folder in Tomcat directories. Therefore I am confused with the command:

"cp deployment/datapusher /etc/apache2/sites-available/"           (Directory not available)

Thank you very much!